# Connecting Back Office back end to Buildfire login page

Tags: buildfire

I am fairly new to coding and have run into a couple of issues that I don't know how to deal with. How do I go about connecting account information (registration / logins) to Back Office software? Primarily, what I am needing to do is when someone logs in or registers an account in our app, I need it to connect to our back end (Back Office) so we can retain their information as it would naturally on the web. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. First is to make an API call from you plugin to your backend. You can ask for current logged in user and/or listen in to the onLogin event using this https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/auth/#onlogin
2. Create a service to your plugin that is always listening in the backend of your app. The benefit is that your plugin doesn’t need to be open to trigger your code. https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/background-services/
3. Backend server to server api. You call the api from your backend to see who registered  https://sdk.buildfire.com/AWSGatewayPublicAPI/#/user/post_user_register the app doesn’t need to be open at all
4. SSO where they register on your backend and use it as the source of truth to login https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/using-single-sign-on-sso/